# RPS game making it say invalid error

Tags: java

I made this Rock Paper scissors game but i cnt figure out how to make it show invalid error when the user enters something other than R,P,S. It would be helpful if any once could tell me how to make it so that it does this. Im a relatively new coder. Thanks in advance for all your help

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RPS {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
String userPlay; //User's play -- "R", "P", or "S" 
String computerPlay = ""; //Computer's play -- "R", "P", or "S" 
int computerInt; 
String response; 


Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
Random generator = new Random(); 

System.out.println("Lets play Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n" + 
                   "Choose your move.\n" + "Rock = R, Paper" + 
                   "= P, and Scissors = S.");

System.out.println();

//Generate computer's play (0,1,2) 
computerInt = generator.nextInt(3)+1; 

//Translate computer's randomly generated play to 
//string using if //statements 

if (computerInt == 1) 
   computerPlay = "R"; 
else if (computerInt == 2) 
   computerPlay = "P"; 
else if (computerInt == 3) 
   computerPlay = "S"; 


//Get player's play from input-- note that this is r
System.out.println("Enter your play: "); 
userPlay = scan.next();

//Make player's play uppercase
userPlay = userPlay.toUpperCase(); 

//Print computer's play 
System.out.println("Your opponents play is: " + computerPlay); 


//See who won. 

if (userPlay.equals(computerPlay)) 
   System.out.println("It's a tie!"); 
else if (userPlay.equals("R")) 
   if (computerPlay.equals("S")) 
      System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors. You win!!");
else if (computerPlay.equals("P")) 
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock. You lose!!"); 
else if (userPlay.equals("P")) 
   if (computerPlay.equals("S")) 
   System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper. You lose!!"); 
else if (computerPlay.equals("R")) 
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock. You win!!"); 
else if (userPlay.equals("S")) 
     if (computerPlay.equals("P")) 
     System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper. You win!!"); 
else if (computerPlay.equals("R")) 
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors. You lose!!"); 
else 
     System.out.println("Invalid user input."); 
}
}
```

Comment: Start by using brackets on your `if` statements. It will make everything **much** easier to organize.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is with loop. You ask to enter player's move, if it is unacceptable you ask again. You continue it until user enters valid string. In code it will look like this

```
//Get player's play from input
boolean moveOk = false;
while (moveOk == false) {
    System.out.println("Enter your play: ");
    userPlay = scan.next();
    //Make player's play uppercase
    userPlay = userPlay.toUpperCase();
    // check that the input is ok
    if ("R".equals(userPlay) ||
        "P".equals(userPlay) ||
        "S".equals(userPlay)) {

        moveOk = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Bad input, try again!");
    }
}
```

If you want to show error and then stop the program, instead of creating the loop you can use simple `if` with similar condition and when input is incorrect print error message and use `return`.

Also you could make your code easier to understand if you divide your conditions in parts, for example by user input. See example below.

```
//See who won. 
String result = "";
if (userPlay.equals(computerPlay)) {
    result = "It's a tie!";
}
if (userPlay.equals("R")) {
    if (computerPlay.equals("S")) {
        result = "Rock breaks scissors. You win!!";
    } 
    if (computerPlay.equals("P")) {
        result = "Paper covers rock. You lose!!";
    }
}
if (userPlay.equals("P")) {
    if (computerPlay.equals("S")) {
        result = "Scissor cuts paper. You lose!!";
    } 
    if (computerPlay.equals("R")) {
        result = "Paper covers rock. You win!!";
    }
}
if (userPlay.equals("S")) {
    if (computerPlay.equals("P")) {
        result = "Scissor cuts paper. You win!!";
    } 
    if (computerPlay.equals("R")) {
        result = "Rock breaks scissors. You lose!!";
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Also you could use `switch` statement.